# 404 error when uploading large files (4mb+) - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I have wasted essentially my entire day working on this. It seems that large uploads worked previously, but now they don't even though I have all the settings I should need in my web config. Every singly time I upload, it processes very briefly then gives me a 404 - File or directory not found. I have searched far and wide and cannot seem to figure this out. If I lower the limits below the size of the file, it will throw an actual system exception, but when I raise it again it returns to a 404.

Below are the sections I added to my web.config file a while ago:

to the base:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" maxRequestLength="4000000" />
```

and to the system.webServer section:

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I also overrode the applicatioHost.config setting for allowing the web config to override machine level settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i answered my own question. both limits were too low. increased both, success.

Comment: Hi Brick, Is there is a rule that both attributes should have same values like maxAllowedContentLength="2147482624" and maxRequestLength="2097151"

Answer (score 3):

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" maxRequestLength="4000000" />

<security>
   <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The two different settings have different units:

maxRequestLength is in Kilobytes
maxAllowedContentLength is in Bytes